# Linked Lists Java SearchAll and Boolean Remove

Tags: java, list

```
package phonelist;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class LinkedList {

    private Node head;
    private int size = 0;

    public LinkedList() {
        load(); // Load a contacts from a file
    }

    public void add(Contact contact) {

        Node newNode = new Node(contact, null);
        size++;
        if (head == null) {
            newNode.setNextNode(head);
            head = newNode;
        } else {
            Node c = head;
            while ((c.getNextNode() != null)) {
                c = c.getNextNode();
            }

            newNode.setNextNode(c.getNextNode());
            c.setNextNode(newNode);
        }
    }

    public boolean remove(String name) {


        return true;
    }



    public Contact search(String name) {

        return null;
    }


    public String getAll() {

        return null;
    }

    /** Save contacts to a text file **/
    public void save() {
        if (size == 0) {
            return;
        }

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System. in );
        try {
            PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter("contacts.txt");

            if (head != null) {
                Node currentNode = head;
                do {
                    Contact contact = currentNode.getContact();
                    outFile.println(contact.getName() + "," + contact.getNumber());
                    currentNode = currentNode.getNextNode();
                } while (currentNode != null);
            }

            outFile.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Cannot find that file");
        }
    }

    /** Load contacts from a text file **/
    public void load() {
        try {
            FileReader file = new FileReader("contacts.txt");
            Scanner inFile = new Scanner(file);

            while (inFile.hasNext()) {
                String contact = inFile.nextLine();
                int index = contact.indexOf(',');
                String name = contact.substring(0, index);
                String number = contact.substring(index + 1, contact.length());
                add(new Contact(name, number));
            }

            inFile.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Cannot find that file");
        }
    }

}
```

I cannot figure out how to remove a specific node, nor how to search properly. It keeps giving me a node location not what i have added. I have spent the last 5 hours working on this and I am unable to finish the rest without at least being able to search. If someone could give me a few pointers on here to begin or give me examples, it would be much appreciated.

Here is a way I have tried the remove method.

```
public boolean remove(String name) {
  if (name.equals(name)) {
  remove(name);
  return true;
  } else {
  return false;}}
```

Node Class

```
package phonelist;


public class Node {
private Contact contact;
private Node next;

public Node(Contact contact, Node next) {
    // Do something here
this.contact = contact;
this.next = next;
}

public void setNextNode(Node next) {
    // Do something here
this.next = next;
}

public Node getNextNode() {
    // Replace return null with something useful
    return next;
}

public Contact getContact() {
    // Replace return null with something useful
    return contact;
}
}
```

Contact Class

```
package phonelist;

public class Contact {
private String name;
private String number;

public Contact(String name, String number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}
}
```

In the LinkeList class Ive created a toString() method but i am currently only printing out a node location in memory not the actual data. Ideas?

```
 @Override
public String toString() {
    return "LinkedList{" + "head=" + head + ", size=" + size + '}';
}


public String getAll() {

System.out.println(toString());
return null;
```

Comment: Please post your attempts and explain exactly how it doesn't work.

Comment: if (name.equals(name)) {
      remove(name);
      return true;
      } else {
        return false;
Whenever i try something like this it keeps saying name not found even when i use head.getNextNode().getContact().getName(); to bring in the name from my contact class

Comment: Please post your code *in your question*. If it results in an exception, please also post the *complete stack trace* or the complete error message from your compiler.

Answer (score 2):

## The algorithms "in words"

### Search

As for searching, you can just write a while loop in your `search(String name)` method that starts at the head and iterates through the list the same way you've done in your add function (where you've done:

```
Node c = head;
while ((c.getNextNode() != null)) {
    c = c.getNextNode();
}
```

). But instead of stopping once the current contact being pointed to has null as it's next contact, stop when the current contact has the name you're searching for. Be careful to also stop once you have reached the end of the list in the case where you *don't* find the contact (so basically just add something to the existing loop condition).

### Remove

As for removing an element, it's the same as searching, but with an additional step. It will be like the loop to search, but this time you'll want to stop when *the next* contact is the one you're looking for. Then set the 'next' reference  of the current node to the node after the contact you want to remove.

I could code this up with an example, but I'll leave that to you so you will be sure to understand it :-) Good luck!

Comment: I was trying name.equals(name) in order to stop but i could not get it to stop. The system says name is not found

Comment: We'll need more information to be able to help you with that- an example of your code perhaps. Two things to mention: 1. If you want to have a conversation, 'chat' is the appropriate place. We need to be careful not to have a dialog in this comment thread. 2. When you can only define your problem as 'x fails', it is usually most useful to do a little code-stepping to investigate yourself. There are lots of great tools for this. [Eclipse's debugger](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html) is widely used and straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Please see explanation in Javadoc . Let me know if you have any question.

---

**Search Method**

```
/**
 * 
 * @param name this the name of the contact to search for. If list has two
 *        contacts with same name the first one found will be used
 * @return Contact 
 */
public Contact search(String name) {
    Node currentNode = head;
    Contact contact = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (currentNode.getContact().getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            contact = currentNode.getContact();
            break;
        }
        currentNode = currentNode.getNextNode();
    }

    return contact;
}
```

**Remove Method and helper method searchNodeOneBeforeTheTargetNode**

```
/**
     * 
     * @param name of the contact to remove
     * @return True for successful removal
     */
    public boolean remove(String name) {
        Node node = searchNodeOneBeforeTheTargetNode(name);
        boolean removalSuccessfull = false;
        if (node != null) {
            node.setNextNode(node.getNextNode().getNextNode());
            removalSuccessfull = true;
        }
        return removalSuccessfull;
    }

    /**
     * Pay attention to this method. Since your linked list a Singly linked
     * list, meaning every node only knows about the next node not the previous.
     * This method return the previous node to of the target node. All that is
     * needed to be done here is that we get the next node of target and
     * attached that to the previous node of the target e.d if we want to remove B from below
     * 
     * A->B->C  A know B but B does not know about A it know about C . To delete B we connect A->C and B is deleted
     * 
     * 
     * 
     * @param name
     * @return
     */
    private Node searchNodeOneBeforeTheTargetNode(String name) {
        Node currentNode = head;
        Node nodeOneBeforeTheTargetNode = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (currentNode.getContact().getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                nodeOneBeforeTheTargetNode = currentNode;
                break;
            }
            currentNode = currentNode.getNextNode();
        }

        return nodeOneBeforeTheTargetNode;
    }
```

**Get All Method** Note your method returns String. If you are getting all elements of linked list which are in this case contacts then it should return some collection. I am using Array as that is most basic.

```
/**
     * 
     * @return Array of all contacts in linked list
     */
    public Contact[] getAll() {
        Contact[] contacts = new Contact[size];
        Node currentNode = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (currentNode != null) {
                contacts[i] = currentNode.getContact();             
                currentNode = currentNode.getNextNode();
            }
        }

        return contacts;
    }
```